# Does model.predict() use use the best weights of the model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am using Keras' EarlyStopping callback function, saving only the best weights and setting a patience of say 10 epochs. I am wondering whether the predict function is using the weights of the last epoch of training or the ones of the best epoch. A minimal example would be:

```
callback = tensorflow.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience = 10, min_delta=0.0003, restore_best_weights=True)

history = model.fit(x_train_noisy, x_train, validation_data=(x_test_noisy, x_test), epochs= 100, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks = callback)
model.save("model.h5")
prediction = model.predict(x_test_noisy)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using `restore_best_weights=True`, yes, the model is set to its best weights after training.

If that was not `True`, you'd have to save the weights during training with a `ModelCheckpoint` callback and later load the saved weights.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you have any documentation you could point me towards, where it says so? The official documentation of keras unfortunately is not mentioning this.

Comment: @TUD_123, it's in the official documentation: https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/ (Arguments: restore_best_weights: ....)